# Intptr Handle are not Garbage Collected

Tags: c#-4.0, garbage-collection, pinvoke

Native Window Handles are not garbage collected. So after searching on internet I came to know about SafeProcessHandle below on MSDN article. Tried to implement it but i am receiving 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestHandle
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

            int processID = 0;
            int threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);


            using (Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processID))
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(256);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, text, 256);
                Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());                    
            }

            Console.WriteLine(hWnd);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        char tmp = 'q';
        while (Console.Read() != tmp) ;
    }
}
}
```

In order to obtain currently opened window, I am trying to implement it through Timer and also tried through while loop but it increases memory footprint and if i am designing a long running Console Application which works till PC is running then things are getting worse. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You don't own these windows so don't need to clean up. No code here attempts to clean up. No use of sage handles can be seen. Services don't have access to interactive desktops. Please make it clear what you want to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: It is a long running Console Application to obtain Running Window. Yes, you are true but if you will run this code in a Timer then you will see memory footprint is increasing constantly.

Answer (score 0):

`GetForegroundWindow` returns a window handle that you do not need to tidy up. The code shown in the question do not leak and has no need for safe handles. You use safe handles when you have a requirement to tidy up unmanaged resources. That is not the case here.

If indeed you do have a problem with a leak, it is not related to the code shown which does not need to be modified.

**Update**

Regarding your update it is pointless to obtain the process ID and a .net Process object. You don't use them. You can request the window text with the window handle, as indeed you do.

Nothing here suggests a leak of any unmanaged resource and nothing here requires safe handles. If process memory use grows then that would be the normal behaviour for a GC based process. Each time round the loop a new StringBuilder object is created.

The code can be much simpler:

```
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(256);
    while (true)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowText(hWnd, text, 256);
        Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(hWnd);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

Note that I am re-using a single StringBuilder object which will at least prevent steady increase of managed memory use.

You should also check return values of API calls for errors but I don't want to go into the detail of how to do that here.

Comment: Sir, I have updated my code. And every single second it is increasing memory bytes.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. Now you ask a different question.  Imagine how that gives me encouragement.

Comment: I am stuck with the issue and in order to explain it better I put the entire source code. I truly appreciate your concern over here.

Comment: I've given you an update. That's it. You asked about safe window handle. Please don't turn this into personal debugging with ever changing question. That just annoys. Please visit [help].